# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k^{2}+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Could please give me a hint.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k^{2}+1}$$

It looks like an integral, but I failed to figure out the function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $a_k = \dfrac{k}{k^2+1} \Rightarrow L = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_n}{n} = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$, by Cesaro theorem.

Answer (score 7):

HINT: For any $k\in \mathbb{N}$:
$$
\frac{k}{k^2+1}\leq \frac{k}{k^2}\leq \frac{1}{k}\leq \int_{k-1}^k\frac{1}{t}\, dt.
$$

Answer (score 3):

If you want it in an integral form, here's your limit.

$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n}\int^1_0 \frac{2x \;dx}{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \left|\ln \left|x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}\right|\right|_0^1$

Comment: Where does the $\int_0^1$ come from? Are you saying this $L$ is the same value of the sum in OPs question?